# Is it possible to clear casper rw in Ubuntu 20.04 live session?

Tags: live-usb, persistence

In Ubuntu 20.04 I created persistence using Rufus for the live session. How can I clear the persistence storage completely? There is a casper rw folder in it.

Comment: Can you provide more information what you did you try and what error you receive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Clear Persistence in Bootable USB.

If you use `sudo -H nautilus` to delete everything in the **casper-rw** or **writable** partition, (ie the work and upper folders), and reboot a couple times you will end up with a fresh new persistence partition with new work and upper folders.

If you want to remove the persistence partition, boot a second Live USB and open GParted and Format the casper-rw partition or remove the casper-rw label.

Comment: i dont want to remove persistence partition. To delete everything in casper rw if i format the casper rw partition from "disks" during live session does it remove the persistence storage?

Comment: If you format the casper-rw partition it will remove the `casper-rw` label, which will remove persistence. In  which case, if you want persistence, you will need to re-label the partition. It is easier to just delete the **upper** and **work** folders that are inside casper-rw, using files, (`sudo -H nautilus`). They will be automatically rebuilt the next boot. Personally I mostly use GParted when working on partitions.

Comment: thanks now i can delete(sudo -H nautilus) folders inside casper rw

Comment: Thank you for letting us know it worked for you.